# App Center Accpetance rules

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-center

I am trying to get my app accepted to the Facebook App Center. I have done everything that the guide says that I need to do prior to submission. In the guide, it tells me that once I have done all tasks, submit the application and it will be reviewed. If declined, a list of needs will be given. When I submit my application this is what I get:
"Ineligible Submission
Your app does not have high enough ratings and user engagement to be eligible for the App Center at this time."

What do I need to do to meet this criteria? Are there specifics?